# What is the origin of != in the meaning "not equal to"?

Tags: etymology, internet, programming, software, computing

As a programmer I have always assumed that using != as meaning *not equal to* when writing text (usually on the internet) came from programming languages. Is this true or is the origin different?

Comment: Doesn't this belong on programmers.SE more?

Comment: Well, I bet it could have been posted there. Personally I think english.SE is better since I'm asking about its use in regular text, like when people write stuff like "biking != fun".

Comment: A point not mentioned in any answer yet (but which could be added to almost any of them, which is why I'm mentioning it here): some of these languages use ! for NOT already, so != is slightly more natural than <>, or the other ASCII-only operators from the Wikipedia article mentioned in one answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols - list Exclamation mark (or "bang") as negation in Math.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C and the unix shells use != for not equal, it comes from the maths symbol ≠.

The earlier computer langauge FORTRAN that was (and is) used for more mathematical work uses .ne. because it was invented before the symbols on keyboards were standardised

Comment: No, FORTRAN did not use .ne. because of a lack of symbol standardization, but mainly because when the relation operators .EQ., .NE., etc. were added in the forth standard version of the language, the necessary parsing of the = symbol (used for assignment) was already quite complicated, and overloading it for the equals relation was considered undesirable.

Comment: I also disagree with this, on the basis that it has more to do with C's choice to make `!` be the boolean negation operator. Other languages existed that used `/=`, which when juxtaposed look much more like the mathematical symbol `≠`. The C designers purposely chose against that.

Comment: @TED it's also because you need a unary NOT operator and "|" "/" are both already used

Comment: My college professor claimed that .NE. was carelessly bolted on the the Fortran standard -- so much so, he said, that you can still see the bolts.

Comment: @MartinBeckett - Right. But it is also due to the (formerly) unique features of C that mathematical operators may be combined with the assignment operator to produce a mathematical assignment operator, and that assignment operators *return a result*. In other words, the more normal `/=` boolean op was not available in C because it is already being used for something else that could be used in a boolean context. Writing `if (x /= 2) ` works just fine in C, but it returns true every time unless x is 0 (or an integer type of 1). And it has side-effects. Ick.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is from programming languages such as C and C++.

> The symbol used to denote inequation — when items are not equal — is a
>   slashed equals sign "≠" (Unicode 2260).
>
> Most programming languages,
>   limiting themselves to the ASCII character set, use ~=, !=, /=, =/=,
>   or <> to represent their boolean inequality operator.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#Not_equal).

---

*(Edit: Combining vincente and Mark Hurd's comment with something extra.)*

`!=` may have first appeared in the [B language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/kbman.html), which was a precursor to C. It does not appear in [BCPL](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/clive-on-bcpl.html) which was an inspiration for B, so perhaps the B designers were the first.

And [some languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Standard_relational_operators) (including B and C) use `!`  for logical negation (aka NOT), so `!=` is slightly more natural than `>` and the other ASCII-only operators. Again, BCPL is different: it uses `~a` to mean "NOT a", but uses `a!b` for !(a+b).

Comment: Anybody know what language uses `=/=`? It's kinda cute, but I've never seen it before.

Comment: @T.E.D. [Erlang](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/118268/25708) uses =/= and Prolog uses =\=.

Comment: Just for trivia, `<>` was chosen in some languages because it can be interpreted as "less than or greater than", or in other words, not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this originated in the C language.

Comment: The syntax appears first (that I know of) in the B language that was a precursor to C. It does not appear in BCPL which was an inspiration for B, so perhaps the B designers were the first,

Comment: Note that the (formerly quite popular) Pascal family of languages tended to use `/=` instead. `!=` is a quirk of C that became popular mostly because C's syntax became popular.

Comment: @T.E.D. AFAIK Pascal has always used `<>` for inequality. In my Delphi 7 compiler (based firmly on Pascal), I get an error message when trying to compile `if 1 /= 2 then`, namely `[Error] Unit2.pas(29): Expression expected but '=' found`

Comment: @ReversedEngineer - Yeah, you're right. Decade younger me was wrong. It was ALGOL68 that used /=. Many of the languages influenced by ALGOL borrowed it, but it looks like C and Pascal prominently did not.